# Insert list of strings pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am passing a list of strings into pl sql. What is a good insert each value in the string into a table?

Right now I'm using a binding array in. Net and passing the list into pl sql and using the basic update statement this works but after research I think I should be using a loop to do this.

This works.

```
 Procedure  (p_value in varchar2)
 Insert into mytable (mycolumn)
 Values (p_value)
```

I created a function to split the strings however I am not sure how to replicate the above in a loop.

```
 ParmMyvalue := myfunctionthatseperatesstrings (p_value)
```

P_value contains a, b, c

The end result would be

```
 Mycolumn
 A
 B
 C
```

I'm not sure how to loop through my comma separated list. I'd like to use like a for each loop or something to insert each value

Comment: Would you mind posting your code and the results you're getting, along with sample data and expected outcome? It would make it easier for us to be able to help you.

Comment: why not just batch insert ?

Comment: Do you have an example by chance?

Comment: What does `myFunctionThatSeparatesStrings` return?  Does that return a PL/SQL collection?  If so, then you simply want a `forall` to do the `insert`.

Comment: Yes. Split the function at the , and puts it into a collection. Do you have an example of the forall. Right now I did a loop that goes through each value and inserts the record